# No me funciona ni GET ni POST

Tags: php, html

Puse estos dos inputs dentro de un `<form>` para enviar información mediante POST:

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="w-100">

      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="prueba">
      <input class="boton-rojo-block" value="Eliminar">

</form>
```

La idea era que solo se viera el "botón" de Eliminar, para que cuando se le diera click el method pasase a ser POST y se enviara la información que se encuentra en el input hidden.

Esa información la iba a usar con un script de PHP que se encuentra en la misma pagina, por eso el  `action=""` vacío.

El problema es que no funciona el POST, y lo comprobé así:

```
<?php
     echo "<pre>";
     var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
     echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Ahí pude ver que el método no cambiaba a POST, se quedaba en GET a pesar de darle click al input del formulario.

Y no solo eso, sino que también probé con GET y la información tampoco no se pasa a la URL.

Lo mas raro es que en el mismo proyecto ya hice un formulario con el método POST y funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tu boton no es de tipo submit y tambien no tiene la propiedad name, deberia ser en el siguiente modo:

```
<?php
$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['bottone-rosso'])){ //check if form was submitted
  $value= $_POST['id']; //get input text
  $message = "Success! You entered: ".$input;
}    
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" class="w-100">
  <?php echo $message; ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="prueba">
  <input class="boton-rojo-block" name="bottone-rosso" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda
Saludos!

Comment: upss... se me paso por alto, el name no es necesario pero el `type="submit"` si. Gracias!!!!